# ¿Cómo cambiar de diapositiva en un carousel con botones de acción?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, bootstrap-carousel, bootstrap-5

Tengo un carousel hecho con **bootstrap 5**, el cual funciona bien.

Le coloqué unos botones para que, al momento de dar click en ellos cambie de diapositiva (como sucede con los indicadores).

En la primera diapositiva funcionan bien todos los botones, pero al cambiar a la 2da diapositiva no funciona más.

**Esta es la estructura principal del carousel:**

```html
<div class="car carousel-item active pt-lg-5">
  <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/SF-yellowmovil-wave.png'; ?>);"></div>
  <div class="row col-lg-6 cont-nave">
    <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="">diapositiva1</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn1" class="">diapositiva2</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn2" class="">diapositiva3</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn3" class="">diapositiva4</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn4" class="">diapositiva5</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn5" class="">diapositiva6</button>
    <p class="col-lg-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed imperdiet feugiat ultrices. In vestibulum auctor justo in malesuada.
      Ut sit amet mauris in justo tristique porttitor. Vivamus egestas purus sit amet iaculis euismod. Donec sagittis malesuada vestibulum.
      Vestibulum ultricies pretium feugiat. Nunc mattis mauris vel pharetra porta. Integer ornare porttitor tellus vitae dapibus.</br></br>
      Phasellus ultricies odio nibh, non facilisis tellus feugiat a.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="car carousel-item pt-lg-5">
  <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/SF-bluemovil-wave.png'; ?>);"></div>
  <div class="row col-lg-6 cont-nave">
    <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="">diapositiva1</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn1" class="">diapositiva2</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn2" class="">diapositiva3</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn3" class="">diapositiva4</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn4" class="">diapositiva5</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn5" class="">diapositiva6</button>
    <p class="col-lg-10">Pellentesque condimentum, sem in lobortis consectetur, orci sapien pharetra libero, quis convallis velit odio et nunc.
      Vestibulum bibendum gravida metus at tempus. Morbi ultrices lectus eget ipsum laoreet pretium. Quisque vitae iaculis odio.
      Integer venenatis ornare leo, maximus euismod nulla interdum eget. Nam in mollis sem. Pellentesque nec sollicitudin sem, a consectetur nibh.
      Etiam eget velit et leo rutrum feugiat.</br></br>
      Sed pulvinar sagittis nulla eu mattis. Suspendisse non tincidunt massa. Vestibulum convallis facilisis tortor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Acá el Jquery con la función para cambiar de diapositiva al dar click en alguno de los botones:

```javascript
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#myBtn").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(0);
  });
  jQuery("#myBtn1").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(1);
  });
  jQuery("#myBtn2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(2);
  });
  jQuery("#myBtn3").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(3);
  });
  jQuery("#myBtn4").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(4);
  });
  jQuery("#myBtn5").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(5);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Haz colocado todos los botones con `id` y debes saber que la diferencia entre `id` y `class` es que `id` solo lo puedes usar una vez y `class` muchas veces

Comment: ¿Porque tienes que usar jquery para ello?  ¿No es mejor lo que dice la propia documentación de bootstrap 5 sobre el [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#methods)?  Es decir, algo asi como `var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#mycarousel')` y luego seria `myCarousel.to(x)`  donde x es el numero de diapositiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes comprender en que el identificador `id` solo se puede usar una vez, si colocas un mismo `id` en más de un elemento, solo podrás seleccionar el primer elemento, para evitar esto debes cambiarlo a una clase, de la siguiente manera:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".myBtn").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(0);
  });
  jQuery(".myBtn1").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(1);
  });
  jQuery(".myBtn2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(2);
  });
  jQuery(".myBtn3").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(3);
  });
  jQuery(".myBtn4").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(4);
  });
  jQuery(".myBtn5").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").carousel(5);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="car carousel-item active pt-lg-5">
  <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/SF-yellowmovil-wave.png'; ?>);"></div>
  <div class="row col-lg-6 cont-nave">
    <button type="button" class="myBtn">diapositiva1</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn1" >diapositiva2</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn2" >diapositiva3</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn3" >diapositiva4</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn4" >diapositiva5</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn5" >diapositiva6</button>
    <p class="col-lg-10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed imperdiet feugiat ultrices. In vestibulum auctor justo in malesuada.
      Ut sit amet mauris in justo tristique porttitor. Vivamus egestas purus sit amet iaculis euismod. Donec sagittis malesuada vestibulum.
      Vestibulum ultricies pretium feugiat. Nunc mattis mauris vel pharetra porta. Integer ornare porttitor tellus vitae dapibus.</br></br>
      Phasellus ultricies odio nibh, non facilisis tellus feugiat a.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="car carousel-item pt-lg-5">
  <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/SF-bluemovil-wave.png'; ?>);"></div>
  <div class="row col-lg-6 cont-nave">
    <button type="button" class="myBtn">diapositiva1</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn1" >diapositiva2</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn2" >diapositiva3</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn3">diapositiva4</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn4" >diapositiva5</button>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn5">diapositiva6</button>
    <p class="col-lg-10">Pellentesque condimentum, sem in lobortis consectetur, orci sapien pharetra libero, quis convallis velit odio et nunc.
      Vestibulum bibendum gravida metus at tempus. Morbi ultrices lectus eget ipsum laoreet pretium. Quisque vitae iaculis odio.
      Integer venenatis ornare leo, maximus euismod nulla interdum eget. Nam in mollis sem. Pellentesque nec sollicitudin sem, a consectetur nibh.
      Etiam eget velit et leo rutrum feugiat.</br></br>
      Sed pulvinar sagittis nulla eu mattis. Suspendisse non tincidunt massa. Vestibulum convallis facilisis tortor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, en este caso utilice la recomendación de @jhon Maldonado de igual manera ocurre el mismo, al estar en la diapositiva 1 puedo elegir cualquier botón y me lleva a la diapositiva en cuestión, luego no puedo desplazarme entre las diapositivas.

Comment: @kevinrojas si esta es la respuesta adecuada para tu caso debes aceptarla para que tu pregunta no quede pendiente de responde eternamente. Aqui te dejo [un enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) sobre como se aceptan las respuestas correctas y aqui [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) sobre porque es importante aceptarlas.

Comment: gracias @JhonMaldonado, habia colocado mal la clase, por eso no me funcionaba!

Answer (score 0):

Por que no usas el carrousel por defecto de BootStrap, solo cambia las imagenes que le puse y pruebalo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center bg-dark">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active bg-dark" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="active bg-dark" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="active bg-dark" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="images/fondo.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="images/fondo2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="images/fondo3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button class="carousel-control-prev bg-dark" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden bg-dark">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="carousel-control-next bg-dark" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```